# Static home page vs latest posts for SEO

Tags: seo, homepage

Which is better from an SEO perspective: a static well-optimized homepage for the primary keyword (say, primary-keyword.com) of a website, or a homepage featuring the latest posts?

Comment: I would consider only having _snippets_ of posts on the homepage (if you decide to go that route), rather than the full article (if that is what you are implying), otherwise you could run into duplicate content issues.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you mix both of them?

Google likes fresh content, so having latest post will make Search Engines to crawl your homepage more often and rank better. If you also have it optimized for your primary keyword/s, you'll have the perfect homepage.

Here's a [Seo Moz article](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-fresh-factor) explaining the benefits of freshness, which are a bunch of them.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with I.G. Pascual. For an exhaustive list of onsite factors that you should apply to your whole site and not just the homepage see:

http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/on-page-factors

for marrying up good keyword research with good user experience see:

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/searcher-intent-my-main-focus-when-it-comes-to-keyword-research

Its all about searcher intent =)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of question, you shouldn't think about this by SEO. It depends on you want to present to your visitors:

- If you want to present a blog, latest articles is a good practice
- If you want to present a web site, a standard web page can be the best solution (even if it won't be often updated)

Think about visitors and not SEO! Google always says if it's good for visitors, it's good for ranking.

And for your domain name, I advise you to choose a brand (if you can) because it is less spammy than "keyword.com".

Comment: Good SEO seamlessly integrates with good user experience and thinking of the two as seperate entities harms the development of a good site

Comment: I didn't write the contrary! I just said thinking good user experience at first is good pratice and avoid to optimize too much seo.

Comment: Fair enough... =)